# Drawing bitmaps faster on Android canvas or OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es

I currently have a game written using the Android canvas.  It is completely 2D, and I draw bitmaps as sprites on the canvas, and it technically works, but I have a few features that I need to add that will require drawing many more bitmaps on the screen, and there will be a lot more movement.

The app needs more power.

What is the best way to go from this method of drawing Bitmaps on a canvas to using OpenGL so I can draw them faster?

Comment: I would like to add that using libgdx has made it possible to work with my games in a very similar way to working with the Canvas yet I can utilize the full power of OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple platforms out there in the works for making 2d open gl games:
http://www.rokonandroid.com/

http://www.andengine.org/

Unfortunately neither is as well developed as it's iPhone equivalents (cocos2d-iphone), but they will help you get off the ground faster than trying to interface with openGL right off the bat yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get good performance out of a canvas.. but it takes a lot of work..

if you start off with a good performance graphics library, then even if you get a lot of things wrong, you probably will still end up with good performance :) lol

there is a competition running for the fastest drawing library... libgdx is currently winning...

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game